# Race condition with WTS_SESSION_LOGON notification

Tags: windows, winapi, terminal-services

In my windows service I'm trying to perform some specific actions when an interactive user logs on to the system. For that I track [`WTS_SESSION_LOGON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification. Unfortunately today I discovered that that notification comes with a race condition.

For instance, if the user account is configured with a password, after system boot my service starts up and by the time the user enters their password, my service can receive `WTS_SESSION_LOGON` and process it just fine.

The issue happens when there's only one user account that does not have a password. Right after boot, the system automatically logs on that user but my service may start somewhat later and thus it does not receive any notifications of the interactive user logon.

Any idea if there's a way to address this issue? Or at least tell that the user session would auto-logon?

PS. The same race condition happens with `WTS_CONSOLE_CONNECT` notification.

Answer (score 1):

When your service starts, it can use [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833.aspx) to find out which sessions are already present and what their current state is (connected, active/logged-in, etc) before then processing subsequent [`WTS_SESSION_CHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828.aspx) notifications in its [`HandlerEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241.aspx) callback.

Comment: Thanks. But how would I then differentiate it from when someone stops and then starts my service in the Service Manager? It would produce the same result, even though the interactive user might have logged in days ago.

Comment: Does it really matter? When your service starts up, it can see whether a user is already logged in and if so do what it needs to do as if it had received `WTS_SESSION_LOGON` instead.  If you must perform your actions only at the beginning of a new session and are worried about your service starting too late, then configure it to start sooner rather than later.

Comment: Incidentally, there's another worse race condition - if you immediately execute WTSEnumerateSessions after receiving a SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE event, you'll often not see the new session the event data refers to. If you sleep for like 10-100ms and re-execute WTSEnumerateSessions lo and behold now it shows up. Very annoying

Comment: Additional fun fact: the WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF event is fired ~well~ before the session is actually logged off. It's sent basically the once you click "Logoff", but the session persists in WTSEnumerateSessions until all your processes are actually terminated and your session finally disconnects and exits. This can be anywhere up to minutes, depending on what you have running.

Comment: @JonMarnock `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` tells you the session ID that is triggering the event, so you don't need to hunt for it with `WTSEnumerateSessions()`

Comment: No, but if you want to find out more info about the session (such as username, sessiontype, etc) you need to query the WTS API, and for a brief time after the notification, that'll just tell you you're dreaming and that the session doesn't exist.